# CSS Drop Down Broken

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

Okay so here's the deal I made this navigation bar, thanks to a tutorial online, with the code below, everything works BUT the drop down menu, I hover over and nothing happens I've been slaving over this for hours! Thank you very much in advance for anyone's help! I know I'm close to getting it right but I just can't figure it out! Again thank you in advance for your help.

```
<style>

header { font-family: 'blades_gf_freeregular', Futura, Arial, sans-serif; }
nav { height: 41px; background: linear-gradient( #1e7995, #1c2c3f); }
nav ul { margin: 0; }
nav, ul.submenu { background: linear-gradient( #1e7995, #1c2c3f); border-radius: 5px; padding: 0; }
nav ul li { display: block; width: 150px; text-align: center; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
nav li:hover { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); }
nav a { color:#fff; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 10px; }
nav ul.submenu { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); position: relative; boredr-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
nav ul.submenu li { float: none; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid rbga(0,0,0,0.3); }

nav ul li { transition: .3s all linear; }
nav ul li:hover ul.submenu { height: 126px; }

</style>


<header>
<p><img src="assets/images/header32.png" alt="before and after effects title image"/></p>
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu">

<ul role="menubar">
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup=true tabindex="0"><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>

<ul class="submenu" role="menu" aria-hidden=true>

<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="pre-pro.html">Pre-Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="production.html">Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="post.html">Post</a></li>

</ul>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="#">Films</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `sub menu ul` inside the menu `li`

```
<header>
<p><img src="assets/images/header32.png" alt="before and after effects title image"/></p>
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu">

<ul role="menubar">
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup=true tabindex="0"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>

<ul class="submenu" role="menu" aria-hidden=true>

<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="pre-pro.html">Pre-Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="production.html">Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="post.html">Post</a></li>

</ul>
  </li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="#">Films</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eJEgiYoz/3/)**

Comment: -sigh-...I knew it was something REALLY stupid, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have prematurely closed the parent `<li>` element that the submenu should belong to.

http://jsfiddle.net/GL87s/

```
<header>
<p><img src="assets/images/header32.png" alt="before and after effects title image"/></p>
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu">

<ul role="menubar">
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup=true tabindex="0"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>

<ul class="submenu" role="menu" aria-hidden=true>

<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="pre-pro.html">Pre-Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="production.html">Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="post.html">Post</a></li>

    </ul></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="#">Films</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Fixes it.

The only children a `<ul>` should have is `<li>`s. Not another `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close.  Judging by your CSS, the `ul.submenu` should be inside the `<li>` it belongs to.  Just move it inside the `<li>`.  Here's a jsfiddle with the change:

http://jsfiddle.net/8WGKU/

Answer (score 1):

Keep `submenu` inside `<li>`

```
<li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup=true tabindex="0"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>           
    <ul class="submenu" role="menu" aria-hidden=true>
        <li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="pre-pro.html">Pre-Production</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="production.html">Production</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="post.html">Post</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uRNAV/)